# Modules with different annihilator -- can they be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I learnt that two cyclic modules over a commutative ring $R$ are isomorphic if and only if they have the same annihilator. (https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter4.pdf)

Q1) I am interested about non-cyclic modules with different annihilator, can they be isomorphic? Any counter-example?

Q2) I read the proof in the link, it seems that "only if" part can be generalized to free modules, that is, if two free modules over $R$ are isomorphic, then they must have the same annihilator. Is that correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two modules are isomorphic then their annihilators are the same. To see this suppose $f: M \to N$ is an isomorphism of $R$ modules. Let $r$ be in the annihilator of $M$. Then for all $m \in M$, $rm=0$. Now use the fact that $r$ commutes with $f$ and that $f$ is surjective to get that $r$ annihilates $N$. For the other direction use the inverse of $f$.

For the other direction, it should be possible to find a counterexample.

Comment: Of course, counterexamples abound. Take a simple ring $R$, and all of its nonzero (unital) modules have the same annihilator: $\{0\}$. But obviously it has many nonisomorphic pairs of modules.